# Horizontal Nav Tabs Dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nav, dropdown

I've been having some issues with getting a dropdown to be horizontal (and 100% width of the column). I have tried a lot of pieces of code and of course adjusted a ton of things, but have not been able to get this done yet.

**Please keep in mind of the following:**

- Using Bootstrap V3.3.7
- Make sure to use nav-tabs (not normal navbar)
- It should only be 100% of the width of the column

I hope someone is able to help me out with this.

Regards,
Siranix

EDIT: As requested, here's a bootply try / my code: [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/9jAY5VkdGy)

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest you to read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @imSayan Of course I have tried this myself and I also said that in my post. I edited the post and included a bootply (fiddle) example on what I tried.

Comment: Now that's good. Please check my answer. And let me know if its correct.

Comment: Explain what you mean by 100% width of the column. What column? Width of the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `position: static;` , Please let me know is that what you want.

```css
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
}
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display:table; 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center; 
  left:0; 
  right:0;
}
.dropdown-menu>li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">General </a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Example Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu suf-ver-tabdropdown">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Second Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Third Tab</a></li>
</ul>
```